# Maui Blazor Android Install Apk Programmatically

Tags: c#, android, blazor, maui

I have a Maui Blazor Android app and i have created an updater which is checking for a new version and downloading it then to the Microsoft.Maui.Storage.FileSystem.AppDataDirectory

Until here, everything is fine and working but how can i execute the downloaded apk file now?

I already tried with System.Diagnostics.Process.Start but this is always throwing an permission error. Even if i gave Manage/Read/Write permission to External Storage.

I am relative new to the hole android stuff and Maui with Blazor so please start by zero.

Thank you

Comment: MAUI and Blazor together? MAUI is for cross-plattform, while Blazor is a web-framework, AFAIK. What's the purpose of a cross-plattform web-app?

Comment: You can use Blazor to create MAUI application. It is not really that different.

Comment: This is difficult to explain. In android up to 24, you can use Uri.FromFile and REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES in manifest. 24+ you need to use provider. If you use External Storage, and if it is 10, you can use "requestLegacyExternalStorage", and 11+ you need to use special permission (google is behaving like apple now, you need to prove your app needs it, so you can use it). You will need a lot of platform specific code. Search the same question for Xamarin. Good luck.

Comment: You can share the Blazor Code for a web application and for Maui. So you have to write the razor pages just once and can then reuse them. Its also nice because you programm every page with razor (html/css)

Comment: You can check the [Blazor official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/?view=aspnetcore-7.0), it could be helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar problem this year and it wasn't fun in the slightest :)
I tried this code with app update for the same app so ie Tetris.apk with update for Tetris.apk on Android 10, 12, 13.

In order for updates to work on Android  >= 10 you need to create a

- File provider configuration inside AndroidManifest.xml

  Place it inside the <application> tag. the name and authorities should match your application name specifiled in the <application> tag  [Project.Application].fileprovider

  ```
  <provider
              android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
              android:authorities="[Project.Application].fileprovider"
              android:exported="false"
              android:grantUriPermissions="true">
              <meta-data
                  android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                  android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
          </provider>
  ```

  You will need to add the following permissions

  ```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES"/>
  ```
- File paths settings in `Android\Resources\xml\` `file_paths.xml`

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <files-path name="internal_files" path="."/>
    <!-- 'path="."' means the root of the app's internal storage directory -->
  </paths>
  ```

Here come's the good part.

Windows and android share a common space for app files that's in maui located under `FileSystem.Current.AppDataDirectory;`

Downloading the `new_app.apk` there is the easiest way.

### C# code

```
#if ANDROID
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Widget;
using System.Reflection;
#endif

namespace Application.Update;

[Activity(Label = "App updater", LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTop)]
public class ApplicationUpdateService: Activity
{
  public async Task AndroidUpdate(string apkFileName = "update.apk")
  {
      string apkFilePath = Path.Combine(FileSystem.Current.AppDataDirectory, apkFileName);
      Java.IO.File apkFile = new Java.IO.File(apkFilePath);
  
      // Use the FileProvider to get a content URI for the file
      Android.Net.Uri apkUri = FileProvider.GetUriForFile(Android.App.Application.Context, "[Project.Application].fileprovider", apkFile);
  
      // Create an Intent to install the APK
      Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView);
      intent.SetDataAndType(apkUri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
      intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask | ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission);
  
      // Start the installation process
      Android.App.Application.Context.StartActivity(intent);
  }
}
```